# Angularjs: angular is not defined

Tags: angularjs, node.js, angularjs-directive, gulp

Hello i'm following this script  https://github.com/rpocklin/angular-scroll-animate I do everything in this link but my data not showing and i get error in my console : angular is not defined
any idea please ?

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="portfolios">
  <head>

    <base href="/">

    <title> - CV</title>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">

    <link rel="icon" href="assets/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">

    <!-- build:css app.css -->

    <!-- bower:css -->
    <!-- endinject -->
<script src="bower_components/angular-scroll-animate/dist/angular-scroll-animate.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/css/app.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/css/animate.css">

    <!-- endbuild -->


  </head>
  <body>

    <div ng-view></div>

    <!-- build:js app.js -->

    <!-- bower:js -->
    <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-scroll-animate/dist/angular-scroll-animate.js"></script>
    <!-- endinject -->

    <!-- inject:js -->
    <script src="views/home/home.controller.js"></script>
    <script src="views/home/home.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <!-- endinject -->

    <!-- endbuild -->

    <script src="http://localhost:35729/livereload.js?snipver=1"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: script loading order is wrong ... can't load dependencies of a framework or library before first loading the main script

Comment: @charlietfl how show me example ?

Comment: use your all scripts in `<head>` tag and at the very first, load `angular.js` file

Answer (score 0):

Call your script files properly :

```
<head>

<base href="/">

<title> - CV</title>

<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">

<link rel="icon" href="assets/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">

<!-- build:css app.css -->

<!-- bower:css -->

<!-- bower:js -->
<script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-scroll-animate/dist/angular-scroll-animate.js"></script>
<!-- endinject -->

<!-- inject:js -->
<script src="views/home/home.controller.js"></script>
<script src="views/home/home.js"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>

<!-- endinject -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/css/app.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/css/animate.css">

<!-- endbuild -->

</head>
```

Comment: Not work it's not showing my data still error in my console  Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined

Comment: May be that angular.js file is not properly added in their respective folder, because your code is proper or it may be possible that you are missing something, or if you are using angular file from bower then use it from somewhere else.
Mostly this error get when your `ng-app` doesn't get module properly because of lib.

Comment: i get error in my console and my data not showing Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module portfolios due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module angular-scroll-animate due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'angular-scroll-animate' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.

Comment: exactly.! here you forgot to load `ngAnimate` in your module or you missed the `<script>` sequence here for animate

Comment: i have already load script for animate <script src="bower_components/angular-scroll-animate/dist/angular-scroll-animate.js"></script>

Comment: can I see your js file where you have your module. because in your module you have to define `angular.module("myApp", ["ngAnimate"] ...` like this

Comment: `'use strict';

var apps=angular.module('portfolios',["angular-scroll-animate","ngAnimate"]);
  apps.controller('HomeCtrl', function ($scope) {

   $scope.postlogo="testR";
  $scope.postbehind="A";
  $scope.title1="Développeur Mobile";
  $scope.title2="& Web";
 

  });
`

Comment: <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js"></script>